# How to read text input from user?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="third">
    <p>This site requires a password.</p>
    <button onclick="password()">Enter password</button>
    <center><img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/e0frqo.png"></center> 
</div>
<script>
function password() {
    var password = readLine("Enter the password to continue");
    if(password == "testpwd"){
        alert("Status: |Authorized|  Your access has been granted. ------>Go to testwebsite.com/main.html<------     ||Have a nice day||");
    } else {
        alert("Status: Unauthorized Access. Access denied. Try again or leave");
    }
}
</script>
```

Please help me figure out the solution. Im new to html. Please no fancy words I can't understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `<center>` in 2017? What is this madness?

Comment: I told u I was a nub

Comment: There are so many issues in your code that I won't address, but the main problem is that `readLine` is not defined anywhere. If you are looking for an easy way to get user input (for learning purposes), use `prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
readLine("Enter the password to continue");
```

To this

```
prompt("Enter the password to continue", "password");
```